# Why is the `N` function giving me the wrong result when using WolframScript?

Tags: scripting, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am using `wolframscript.exe` to learn mathematica and I would expect the following code to return `0.7071`:

```
Print[N[Sin[Pi/4],5]];
```

But instead, when ran using:

`wolframscript.exe -file "myfile.wl"`

I get the following output instead:

`` 0.7071067811865474617`5. ``

Am I misunderstanding how `N` works?

Comment: `N[Sin[Pi/4], 5] ` indicates that you want the precision tracked and controlled to provide a result with a precision of 5 digits. It does not control the display of the number. The `\`5` in the result indicates that the result achieved a precision of `5` digits; the rest of the digits are what is stored.

Comment: Ok I see, so how do I control the display so that it's no more than 5 digits?

Comment: I don't use `wolframscript` but have you tried [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html)

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yep that answers it! Syed already posted this. Thank you both.